# Why don't I get StackOverflowError while using Arrays.sort(Object[] a) on large array?

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

Every Recursive function call takes space on thread stack.
In Java, Arrays.sort(Object[] a) using merge sort. Merge sort using recursive call of function. Why don't we get StackOverflowError for large array-list?

I searched about, In which case I should use recursion or stack, but i did not find clear cut answer?

Comment: Because the log(base 2) of 2147483647 is  about 31, and that's really not that deep?

Comment: Stack overflows (which are `Error`s) are thrown by the JVM when the stack is overflown. You're more likely to exceed the heap with an array that's too large.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort doesn't use the classical textbook version of merge sort, but rather a far more sophisticated version based on TimSort [as you can read here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29).

Additionally, in Java the stack size isn't a fixed limit, but something you can set as an option of the JVM.

You can extremely easy generate an OutOfMemory exception or Stack limit errors if you try, but (thankfully) library functions are designed to try and avoid it.

Comment: I saw Arrays.sort(Object[] a) implementation on this link : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29

Comment: Your reference is coming, I think, from Java6. The updated code goes:

Comment: public static void sort(Object[] var0) {
        if(Arrays.LegacyMergeSort.userRequested) {
            legacyMergeSort(var0);
        } else {
            ComparableTimSort.sort(var0, 0, var0.length, (Object[])null, 0, 0);
        }

    }

Answer (score 0):

A typical java stack is at least 64k in size. Since the idea of a merge sort is to split the array in 2 every step, you'd need at least lets say 3000 splits to get a stack overflow. Say you had an Object array with sizeof 32 bits (ie approx 4 billion) elements, that's still MUCH MUCH smaller than 64k. So Arrays.sort is not prone to stack overflow.